# Why input takes two times to update?

Tags: php, forms, post, submit

I've created a page where the user gets some information based on two dates (like 01/01/2019 and 04/04/2019). The user chooses both dates, which are sent to my sql query.

My issue is that I need to press the submit button twice for the dates to update.

From what I could see, the code is getting the dates from the previous submit and not the current one. For example, if I change one of the dates from 01/01/2019 to 01/02/2019, it will still be showing the info with 01/01/2019 as a date. I know that because I put some echos on the code and I can see that it's getting the previous value.

I've already tried the solutions from [in php, why input form when submit it takes 2 times pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086825/in-php-why-input-form-when-submit-it-takes-2-times-pressed), but nothing worked.

Here is the code where the user inputs the dates:

```
 <form action="code.php?titulo=Entrada_De_Soja_por_Variedade&codpag=soja&ini=<?php echo $ini ;?>&fin=<?php echo $fin ;?>" method="post">
    <input name="ini" id="ini"  type="date" value = "<?php echo $ini2 ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $ini ?>" >
    <input name="fin" id="fin" type="date"  value = "<?php echo $fin2 ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $fin ?>">
    <input style="width: 120px; height: 30px; font-size:14px;" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

$ini is the initial date and $fin is the final.

On the same code.php, I use:

```
$ini = $_POST['ini'];
$fin = $_POST['fin'];
```

On the sql query, I use:

```
$ini = $_GET['ini'];
$fin = $_GET['fin'];
```

What I need to know is if I'm using the right strategy to with $_POST and $_GET and if there is a way to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance and feel free to ask for more details if you need.

Comment: You're using the same variable name for `POST` and `GET` values. Are they in the same page?

Comment: @dm707 Nope, but doesn't `&ini=<?php echo $ini ;?>&fin=<?php echo $fin ;?>` do the job of "sharing" them between the pages?

Comment: I think you should use the `POST` data to make de query. The `GET` values depends the browser to be refreshed to get new values from your form

Comment: @dm707 It worked partially. Now both $ini and $fin in all pages are correct. But `<form action="code.php?titulo=Entrada_De_Soja_por_Variedade&codpag=soja&ini=<?php echo $ini ;?>&fin=<?php echo $fin ;?>" method="post">` is still getting the old $ini and $fin.

Comment: Thanks  @dm707. Screeload solved my problem with the submit and you solved the issue of "sharing" the values between the pages. I have solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass variables via "POST" and recieve them via "GET".

Also, you don't need to put the vars into the action URL, as they get appended automaticly when using method "GET".

If you want the dates visibile inside the URL (to share the link) you could use this on the form-page:

```
 <form action="code.php" method="get">
<input name="ini" id="ini"  type="date" value="<?php echo $_GET['ini']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $ini; ?>" >
<input name="fin" id="fin" type="date"  value="<?php echo $_GET['fin']; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $fin; ?>">
<input style="width: 120px; height: 30px; font-size:14px;" type="submit" value="Search" />
```

For more information on how "GET" and "POST" work, have a look at this:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Comment: Thank you @Screenload. I should've used echo $_GET['ini'] instead of  echo $ini. I have solved my problem.